# Revert Xcode 4.5 new XIB files to iOS<6

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, ios6, xcode4.5

i've installed **Xcode 4.5** with **iOS6 SDK** and others old SDKs (from 4.3 to 6.0) for testing purpose.

Beautiful, but there is a **BIG** problem!

> A new XIB file is generated for iOS6 compliant!

This is a problem, because my app need to run on *older devices*, not only 6.0+!
When i load the new view (ios6) in a 5.1 device, it silently crash with this error:

> 2012-09-24 22:00:17.090 App[14524:11f03] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason:
>   'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

How can i remove extra lines in XIB to make (xib and app) compatible with older ios version?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try changing this option of the xib:

[image]

Also make sure that **Use Autolayout** is off, because it's a iOS 6.0 feature.

[image]

Comment: **Autolayout** fix the issue! Well.